# Is there a connection between Jupiter's orbital period and the Sun's solar cycles?

Tags: the-sun, jupiter, magnetic-field, orbital-mechanics, core

The cycle of solar maximums and solar minimums are each about 11 years, which is close to the orbital period of Jupiter. I thought it was a numerical coincidence, until google turned up some results of a possible connection. A lot of it is beyond my head though.

I was under the impression that there are gaps in our knowledge regarding Jupiter's core, which would likely be the driver of its magnetic field. And since solar cycles are related to sunspot activity, which in turn is related to the magnetic field of the Sun, I am struggling to find even a basic understanding of the cause-effect relationship (if there is one).

Is there a connection between Jupiter's orbital period and the Sun's solar cycles? Or is it blind speculation?

Comment: Related questions (with answers) [Are we sure the solar cycle is not related to the orbit of Jupiter ?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/are-we-sure-solar-cycle-is-not-related-to-the-orbit-of-jupiter?rq=1) and [What are some theories to explain the 11 year solar cycle ?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-are-some-theories-that-explain-the-11-year-solar-cycle?rq=1)

Comment: Jupiter's own magnetic field is highly unlikely to affect this. However, apart from "numerological" studies, there are other connections examined: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00641